# How to filter an array with RxJS operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs, rxjs5

Hello to every one i am new to RxJs and reactive programming i would like to filter an array like this:

```
let subscription = Rx.Observable.from([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],[{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}]);
```

if i have one array a i can do this:

```
let subscription = Rx.Observable.from([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]);


subscription.filter(x => x.id === 1).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

But how i can to do with the second array?

Comment: Do you want to emit all the {id : n} object from your two arrays?

Comment: yes i like to search from both array the {id: n}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know you'll always have array of arrays you can flatten the array and then run `filter`:

```
const o = Rx.Observable.of([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}])
  .concatMap(array => array) // flatten the array into single emissions
  .filter(x => x.id === 1)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I'm using `.of` that accepts multiple arguments. However it takes them as they are unlike the `from` method that iterates the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions. The easy way is just to create the right observable.

- You could directly create the right observable by concatenating the array in your input of from:

  ```
  let subscription = Rx.Observable.from([{id: 1}, {id: 3}].concat([{id: 1}]));
  ```
- You could use Rx.Observable.of which directly takes as many arguments as value in the created Observable and use the spread operator:

  ```
  let subscription = Rx.Observable.of(...[{id: 1}, {id: 3}].concat(...[{id: 1}]));
  ```
- You could also merge two different observables:

  ```
  let subscription = Rx.Observable.from([{id: 1}
                        .merge(Rx.Observable.from([{ id: 1}]);
  ```

There are possibly other solutions that could work like using an array of array and then flatMapping the array.

Comment: yes that very nice. But what about in case where i receive from an API and is an already mult array. ?

Comment: It's an array of arrays? If so, the flatMapping should work. subscription.flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.from(x))